# Angular ul, cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport list, keyboard selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cdk

Trying to create an **Autocomplete** component functionality.

When a user starts typing, a small window pops up with options to select from.
I would like the user to be able to pick an option using his keyboard.

Example:
- User typing "Hou"
- Options show ["House", "Houston"]
- User hits **down** keyboard key and hits **enter** to select "house"

My pop up scroll component:

```
<ul class="plDropdown-optionList">
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 200px" itemSize="30">
            <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let option of displayableOptions">
              <button class="plDropdown-option" type="button" (click)="selectOption(option)">
                {{option}}
              </button>
            </ng-container>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting a solution option for anyone looking for this.

I used keyboard event from **Input** tag:

```
<input (keydown)="processInput($event)">
```

Then finding which was pressed:

```
processInput(evt: KeyboardEvent): void
```

Keeping selected reference, and updating it:

```
private _updateIndex(key: string): void {
    switch (key) {
      case Key.ArrowUp:
        if (this.selectedIndex === 0) {
          return;
        }

        this._setIndex(this.selectedIndex -= 1);
        break;

      case Key.ArrowDown:
        this.displayedTags$
        .pipe(
          take(1)
        )
          .subscribe((results) => {
            if (this.selectedIndex >= results.length - 1) {
              this._setIndex(results.length - 1);

              return;
            }

            this._setIndex(this.selectedIndex += 1);
          });
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  private _selectIndex(): void {
    this.displayedTags$.pipe(
      take(1)
    )
    .subscribe((results) => {
      const result = results[this.selectedIndex];

      if (result) {
        this.selectResult(result);
      }
    });
  }

  private _setIndex(index: number): void {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }
```

At HTML file, use this line for highlight the currect line:

```
[ngClass]="{'focus-background': selectedIndex == idx}"
```

it looks like this:

```
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 400px" itemSize="30">
            <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let option of displayedTags$ | async; index as idx" (isSelected)="true">
              <button class="plTagsComponent-option" type="button" (click)="selectResult(option)" (isSelected)="true"
                [ngClass]="{'focus-background': selectedIndex == idx}" (mouseenter)="onHover(idx) ">
                {{option.label}}
              </button>
            </ng-container>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: And what is your solution if the user keeps pressing down until the selected one is below the visible area? Somehow you need to detect the selected item is not visible and scroll it back into view.

Comment: @Halt You are right, this is an issue, in my case option are just a few, so I did not face this problem